# ¿Qué función cumple "setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");"?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una función para poder conectarme a un servidor, y estoy documentando cada línea de código para poderla utilizar en proyectos futuros, y no llego a entender que función cumple esta línea de código:

```
setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Estuve buscando información pero no encuentro algo claro que me llegue a explicar para que funciona.

¿Alguien sabe exactamente la función que cumple?
¡Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asigna al header `Content-type` de una conexión un valor de `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

- La propiedad `Content-type` indica el tipo de contenido, formato o codificación de los datos a enviar.
- El valor `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` como se codificaran los datos antes de ser enviados, en este caso indica que se manipularan datos ASCII simples
  de hecho si no se especifica este es el default.

Ejemplo:

```
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
 connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si ya me quedo claro la función que cumple.